Return columns with a single value
I need help with a sql code.

Return only those Snum with 'Sampling' i.e 1,2,5. Others which include Sampling but also have other TestNames should not be returned.
I used the following sql code which is not returning what I want:
select s.Snum,t.TestName 
from sample s 
join test t on s.Snum = t.Snum
where t.ANALYSIS = 'Sampling'
group by s.TEXT_ID ,s.SAMPLE_NUMBER,t.TEST_NUMBER,t.ANALYSIS 
having count(t.TestName) = 1
order by Snum


Please can you show data for all tables, and the expected result, as text not images.

SELECT X.SNUM,X.TEST_NAME FROM
(
 SELECT C.SNUM,C.TEST_NAME,
 MIN(C.TEST_NAME)OVER(PARTITION BY C.SNUM)AS MIN_PER_ID,
 MAX(C.TEST_NAME)OVER(PARTITION BY C.SNUM)AS MAX_PER_ID
 FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
)AS X
 WHERE X.MIN_PER_ID=X.MAX_PER_ID AND X.MIN_PER_ID='SAMPLING'
 ORDER BY X.SNUM

Using window-functions

Thanks Sergey. That worked perfectly.

Return the Snums having Sampling, except those having non-Sampling.
select Snum from test where ANALYSIS = 'Sampling'
EXCEPT
select Snum from test where ANALYSIS <> 'Sampling'


Your HAVING is not correct. You are just counting the number of rows. You need to count the number of rows which are not 'Sampling'.
Your group by also has too many columns.
select
  s.Snum
from sample s 
join test t on s.Snum = t.Snum
group by
  s.Snum
having count(case when t.ANALYSIS <> 'Sampling' then 1 end) = 0;


Hello This are 2 solutions for solving your problem:
1.using having clause 2.using exists operator
select Snum
from YourTable
group by Snum
having min(Testname)='Sampling' AND max(testname)='Sampling';

select distinct Snum 
from YourTable t1 
where Testname='Sampling'
  and not exists (
                 select * from YourTable t2
                 where t1.Snum=t2.Snum
                 and t2.Testname !='Sampling');

Hope it helps.

This EXISTS is far too complicated, rather simply use EXCEPT, as shown in this answer

@JonasMetzler agree with you but I couldn t come with the same solution. I will vote for that solution using except.
